# Como mostrar datos en un combo box menos uno en especifico

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Me muestra normal todos los datos pero yo necesito mostrar todos los datos menos uno en especifico, por ejemplo necesito enviar un dato para poder indicarle que no me muestre en la consulta SQL y quedaría así:
$sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE estado=1 and idarea<>?;
pero cuando intento mandarlo con $_POST["origen_id"] que es el campo que esta en mi vista no me muestra ¿cómo podría hacerlo de forma correcta? ya he visto el código y desde el mismo js no me lleva el dato.

Lo necesito para que por ejemplo cuando un usuario de determinada área ingrese, y luego haga una transacción desde su área en el select no me muestre el área con el cual ha ingresado pero si todas las demás.

utilizo js / controlador / modelos / vista así:

JS:

```
$.post("../../controller/areas.php?op=combo",                                                            
 function(data, status){                        
     $('#cmbarea').html(data);                  
 });

<?php
require_once("../config/conexion.php");
require_once("../models/Areas.php");
$area = new Areas();
```

CONTROLADOR :

```
switch($_GET["op"]){
         case "combo":
          $datos=$area->get_area();
          if(is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0){
             $html= "<option></option>";
             foreach($datos as $row){
                 $html.= "<option 
                value='".$row['idarea']."'>".$row['area_nombre']." 
                          </option>";
             }
             echo $html;      
         }

      }

  ?>
```

MODELO:

```
<?php
class Areas extends Conectar {

     public function get_area(){
         $conectar= parent::conexion();
         parent::set_names();
         $sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE estado=1;";
         $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
        $sql->execute();
        return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
     }
}
```

?>

VISTA:

```
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control" 
             id="origen_id" 
             name="origen_id" placeholder="" 
             readonly required>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="cmbarea">
               Seleccione Área de Destino: 
              <span class="text-danger"></span>
             </label>
             <div class="col-lg-8">
                <select class="js-select2 
                        form-control" id="cmbarea" 
                        name="cmbarea" style="width: 100%;"
                        data-placeholder="Elegir area de destino">
                        <option></option>
                </select>
                <input type= "hidden" 
                       id="areaSeleccionada" 
                       name="areaSeleccionada" 
                       type="text" value="" required>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre hacerlo era algo tan simple como almacenar en una variable ("area_ingresada" en mi caso) un dato ya obtenido en mi js y luego modificar el controlador y el modelo y asi quedo solucionado, espero les sirva a los que aun no les sale.

JS

```
 area_ingresada = idarea;
 $.post("../../controller/areas.php?op=combo",{area_ingresada:area_ingresada},
  function(data, status){
     $('#cmbarea').html(data);
 });
```

CONTROLADOR

```
<?php
require_once("../config/conexion.php");
require_once("../models/Areas.php");
$area = new Areas();

switch($_GET["op"]){

    case "combo":
         $datos=$area->get_area($_POST["area_ingresada"]);
         if(is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0){
             $html= "<option></option>";
             foreach($datos as $row)
             {
                 $html.= "<option value='".$row['idarea']."'>".$row['area_nombre']."</option>";
             }
             echo $html;      
         }
```

}

MODELO

```
<?php
class Areas extends Conectar {

     public function get_area($area){
         $conectar= parent::conexion();
         parent::set_names();
         $sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE estado=1 and idarea<>?;";
         $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
         $sql->bindvalue(1, $area);
        $sql->execute();
        return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
     }
}
```